# Yii findAll that match at least one of several criteria

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

I am implementing a `simpleQuery` action in Yii to `findAll` records that match at least one of several `CDbCriteria` or if necessary, just some search conditions. For example, I want the user to be able to query my records by typing in one string. That string should be checked against each of four columns, and the result set should include all records that have at least one column matched against the string (with no duplicates). I'm still new to Yii so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have the search input in $search_input field of the model and you want to search all of the three fields - name, title and desc, for that string, you can do -

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('name', $this->search_input, TRUE, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('title', $this->search_input, TRUE, 'OR');
$criteria->compare('desc', $this->serach_input, TRUE, 'OR');
$result = MyModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Comment: When you generate a new model and the CRUD interface, check out actionAdmin() and model->search(). What you search for is implemented there.

Comment: Thanks... and I wasn't even aware of a built-in `$searchInput` property.

Comment: @tacos - $this->search_input is not a built in property. This just refers to a variable you created to capture the users's search input.